# SQL MIN(value) matching row in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a following tables:

TABLE A:

```
 ID          ID NAME      PRICE         CODE      
 00001          B         1000          1       
 00002          A         2000          1       
 00003          C         3000          1
```

Here is the SQL I use:

```
Select Min (ID),
       Min (ID NAME),
       Sum(PRICE)
From A
GROUP BY CODE
```

Here is what I get:

```
ID         ID NAME     PRICE         
00001       A          6000
```

As you can see, ID NAME don't match up with the min row value. I need them to match up.

I would like the query to return the following

```
ID         ID NAME     PRICE         
00001       B          6000
```

What SQL can I use to get that result?

Comment: What's the expected result if there are two different products with the price 1000?

Comment: @ThuanNguyen . . . Why would you want the sum of the prices but the row with the minimum price?

Answer (score 0):

If you want one row, use `limit` or `fetch first 1 row only`:

```
select a.*
from a
order by a.price asc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

If, for some reason, you want the *sum()* of all prices, then you can use window functions:

```
select a.*, sum(a.price) over () as sum_prices
from a
order by a.price asc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` function :

```
select min(id), max(case when seq = 1 then id_name end) as id_name, sum(price) as price, code
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by code order by id) seq
      from table t
     ) t
group by code;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use sub-query

```
select t1.*,t2.* from
(select ID,Name from t where ID= (select min(ID) from t)
) as t1
cross join (select sum(Price) as total from t) as t2
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=a496232b552390a641c0e5c0fae791d1

```
id  name    total
1    B      6000
```