# SQL MIN(value) matching row in PostgreSQL 2

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a following table:

```
  ID          ID NAME      PRICE        DATE             CODE
 00003          E           2000      2018/03/24        null        
 00001          C           3000      2018/03/22         1   
 00001          D           4000      2018/03/23         1  
 00002          F           1000      2018/03/21         2   
 00005          B           1000      2018/03/21         2  
 00004          A           2000      2018/03/24        null
```

I want to group by CODE with min(ID) and get ID NAME match up with the min row value
If have same ID, get ID NAME which Min(DATE)
If the CODE is null, I don't want to group

I would like the query to return the following

```
 ID         ID NAME     PRICE       
00001         C         7000
00002         F         2000
00003         E         2000
00004         A         2000
```

What SQL can I use to get that result?

Comment: I don't understand why `0005` is filtered out but `0004` is in the desired results.

Comment: Your expected result conficts with your requirement.

Comment: How is this different to your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52293206

Comment: 0004 have the code as 'null' while 0005 have the code as 2 same as 0002.

Comment: I am upvoting the question because the question is pretty clear to me.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai 0004 have the code as 'null' so I dont want to group by CODE, 0005 have the code as 2 same as 0002 so I want to group them

Comment: @ThuanNguyen, I know it that's why I was trying to explain it to others.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai  thanks you, I not good at English, so I think it hard to understand

Answer (score 0):

According to sample data you need below query

```
with cte1 as
(
select t.code, min(date1) as date1 ,max(t1.s) as price from t
join

(
select code,sum(price) as s  from t where code is not null group by code
) t1 on t.code=t1.code
group by t.code
),
cte2 as
(
select min(t.id) as id ,t.date1,cte1.price from cte1 join t on cte1.date1=t.date1 group by t.date1,cte1.price
) ,

cte3 as 
(
select cte2.*,t.name from cte2 join t on cte2.id=t.id and cte2.date1=t.date1
) ,
cte4 as
(
select * from cte3 union select id,date1,price,name from t where code is null
) select * from cte4 order by id
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=77e2269b6c7e7b48a8039824e15c66fb

```
id  date1   price      name
1   2018-03-22  7000    C
2   2018-03-21  2000    F
3   2018-03-24  2000    E
4   2018-03-24  2000    A
```

Comment: Price of C should be 7000 not 3000.

Comment: thanks you, but I have add condition using DATE. If when group which have same ID, get ID NAME which Min(DATE)